# problems whit TCP client on esp32

Tags: c, sockets, hardware, esp32

I want to tie pin 12 on high when esp32 receives tcp socket with 1 in it.

I Worte tcp client and server and tested on two computers, worked fine.

I am able to connect esp32 to wifi, receive ip and Mac addres.

problem is this code:

```
  if((network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
  {
    //ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%s : ", perror("socket creation"));
    perror("socket creation");
    return 0;
  }
```

outputs to monitor:

`socket creation: Too many open files in system`

this is code I am uploading to esp32 whit idf.py:

```
#include <stdio.h> //for basic printf commands
#include <string.h> //for handling strings
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h" //for delay,mutexs,semphrs rtos operations
#include "esp_system.h" //esp_init funtions esp_err_t 
#include "esp_wifi.h" //esp_wifi_init functions and wifi operations
#include "esp_log.h" //for showing logs
#include "esp_event.h" //for wifi event
#include "nvs_flash.h" //non volatile storage
#include "lwip/err.h" //light weight ip packets error handling
#include "lwip/sys.h" //system applications for light weight ip apps
/** my includes **/

//wifi libararies
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>

//gppio libaraies
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"

/** define pins **/
#define LED 12

// declare TAG for ESP_LOGI
const char *TAG = "CONNECT TO TCP";
/**end of my code**/

const char *ssid = "";
const char *pass = "";
int retry_num=0;
static void wifi_event_handler(void *event_handler_arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id,void *event_data){
if(event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_START)
{
  printf("WIFI CONNECTING....\n");
}
else if (event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_CONNECTED)
{
  printf("WiFi CONNECTED\n");
}
else if (event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED)
{
  printf("WiFi lost connection\n");
  if(retry_num<5){esp_wifi_connect();retry_num++;printf("Retrying to Connect...\n");}
}
else if (event_id == IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP)
{
  printf("Wifi got IP...\n\n");
}
}

void wifi_connection()
{
  //                          s1.4
  // 2 - Wi-Fi Configuration Phase
  esp_netif_init();
  esp_event_loop_create_default();     // event loop                    s1.2
  esp_netif_create_default_wifi_sta(); // WiFi station                      s1.3
  wifi_init_config_t wifi_initiation = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
  esp_wifi_init(&wifi_initiation); //     
  esp_event_handler_register(WIFI_EVENT, ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, wifi_event_handler, NULL);
  esp_event_handler_register(IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP, wifi_event_handler, NULL);
  wifi_config_t wifi_configuration = {
      .sta = {
          .ssid = "",
          .password = "",
          
         }
  
      };
  strcpy((char*)wifi_configuration.sta.ssid, ssid);
  strcpy((char*)wifi_configuration.sta.password, pass);    
  //esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_INFO, "Kconfig", "SSID=%s, PASS=%s", ssid, pass);
  esp_wifi_set_config(ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &wifi_configuration);
  // 3 - Wi-Fi Start Phase
  esp_wifi_start();
  esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA);
  // 4- Wi-Fi Connect Phase
  esp_wifi_connect();
  printf( "wifi_init_softap finished. SSID:%s  password:%s",ssid,pass);
  
}
int recive_int_from_server(void)
{
// {{{
  //coreate a socket
  int network_socket;
  if((network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
  {
    //ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%s : ", perror("socket creation"));
    perror("socket creation");
    return 0;
  }

  // specify an adress for socket
  struct sockaddr_in server_address;
  server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_address.sin_port = htons(5067); 
  server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.1.175"); //INADDR_ANY

  //connect socket 
  if(connect(network_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)) != 0)
  {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "socket connection");
    return 0;
  }

  //string for server_response
  char server_response[250];

  //recive data from server 
  if(recv(network_socket, &server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0) == -1)
  {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "reciving socket");
    return 0;
  }

  //colose socket
  close(network_socket);

  int resp = -1;
  resp = atoi(server_response);
  ESP_LOGI(TAG,"%i", resp);
  return resp;
// }}}
}

void app_main(void)
{
  char *MSG = pcTaskGetName(NULL);

  nvs_flash_init();

  //devefine dirrection of pin LED (12)
  gpio_set_direction(LED, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

  wifi_connection();
  //connect to server and get int
  while(1)
  {
    int msg = recive_int_from_server();
    ESP_LOGI(MSG, "%i", msg);

    if(msg == 1)
    {
      gpio_set_level(LED, 1);
    }else if(msg == 0)
    {
      gpio_set_level(LED, 0);
    }
    vTaskDelay(1);
  }
}
```

this is tcp_server.c running on linux :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main ()
{
  char server_message[250] = "1 \n\r";

  //coresreate socket
  int server_socket;
  if((server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
  {
    perror("socket");
    return 0;
  }

  //define addres structure
  struct sockaddr_in server_addres;
  server_addres.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addres.sin_port = htons(5067);
  server_addres.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY//inet_addr("20.0.1.1"); 

  //bind socket to specified ip and port
  if(bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addres, sizeof(server_addres)) != 0)
  {
    perror("bind");
    return 0;
  }
  //int n = bind(server_socket, &server_addres.sin_addr) 

  //Listen for connections
  if(listen(server_socket, 1) !=0)
  {
    perror("listen");
    return 0;
  }


  int client_socket;
  if((client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL)) == -1)
  {
    perror("accept");
    return 0;
  }

  //send message
  if(send(client_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0) == -1)
  {
    perror("send");
    return 0;
  }

  //colose socket
  close(server_socket);
  return 0;
}
```

tcp_server is running on armbian

esp code is uploaded from Mac m1 throw dongle and usb to micro-c

any help is apriciated.

Comment: This 'resp = atoi(server_response);' is broken.  You are not sending a NUL-terminated char array, you are not NUL-terminating the received buffer, you ignore any positive recv() return which is the ONLY way to determine how many bytes have been loaded into the buffer.

Comment: ..not that I can understand your posted error, but I felt obliged to point out that you do not understand TCP or C 'strings'.